# How can I wrap multiple `with x() as val_x, ...` in a with statement into function for reuse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, with-statement

I am writing what should've been a simple unit test, but to it turns out I need to mock a bunch of things, and all similar tests will need those. I am using `mock.patch` from standard library, and now the code looks like this:

```
with mock.patch("project.folder.file.SomeClass.method") as mock_this,\
     mock.patch("otherproj.directory.file.AnotherClass.some_method" as mock_that,\
     ... and so on, like 4 other things ...                           :

    mock_this.return_value = True
    mock_that.side_effect = some_side_effect
    ... and more ...
```

So I'd like to wrap all that to some method, let's call it `server_mock_boilerplate`. And I'd like to use it as:

```
# I may want to pass objects for cases where patching a global is needed (sadly it is)
# I probably only will need to output select few of the mocked things
with server_mock_boilerplate(obj1, obj2) as (mock1, mock2, mock4):
    # run test
       ...
    # Maybe change side effect during the test
    mock1.side_effect = something_else
```

But I am not sure how to handle this. I can't return from `with` statement without closing the values and if I just return them without activating them with with, the return type of `mock.patch` is not `MagicMock`.

So how to wrap multiple boilerplate `with` statement entries into a function and then use that function and output the entries into a tuple?

Comment: Maybe not exactly the desired solution but there is [contextlib.ExitStack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack)

Answer (score 0):

How about making the boilerplate function a *generator* that yields the objects? Demo:

```
class Manager:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
  def __enter__(self):
    print('enter', self.value)
    return self
  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    print('exit', self.value)
  def __repr__(self):
    return f'Manager({self.value})'

def boilerplate():
  with Manager(1) as a, Manager(2) as b:
    yield a, b

for a, b in boilerplate():
  print('use', a, 'and', b)

print('done')
```

Output ([try it](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZFNTgQhEIXjllPUDkhaE10ZE4_gGUjRXThEQhOgx-kYT-JmNpp4JU9jNzA_mdlV3quvXkF9_YQ5b0a_339P2dw-_t389g5Tghf0-ErxiQEMZEAp621WSiRypoMtuonkagKsyl0R4LkaR4Z8ptig1h2i9Vnw4vDuDJbFjpSn6It8mrI7S6Zdr_IcqFaF7CBH7Elj_3YRsoBXGXVmpHCxWEs2vL1cfJy4T8kZW0E9WkcxOMwkCvdu8-bwV-JeAibA7ig8FEHXgNmSG1ZXM2bGWCqw_npm235KtCy_dHH0w1JpyVizhtETl_Vi7XCHA_4D)):

```
enter 1
enter 2
use Manager(1) and Manager(2)
exit 2
exit 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

So building off the answer I got and the comment I got, I found out the solution that is the least hacky. In contextlib, there is this decorator: [`@contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager). This can be placed above a function that yields once, if that function is used within a `with` statement, it will be resumed after the `with` using it has closed.

It is intended to wrap things that do not support `with`, but it can be just as well used for wraping an entire with statement:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def mock_boilerplate(param):
    with mock.patch("x") as mock_x, mock.patch.object(param) as mock_param:
        yield (mock_x, mock_param)
    # This line is reached after the with that uses this function closes

# usage
def test_something():
    with mock_boilerplate(someobj) as (unused, mock_someobj):
        # proceed with the test
```

Comment: Hmm, what's the advantage of this? Just that you prefer to see a `with` instead of a `for`, or  something else?